# Advanced Spring @Qualifier

Tags: java, spring, code-injection, autowired

I have:

```
@Component
class MyDecorator{
  private Cache cache;
  /*
  some wrapped methods like get put remove
  */
}
```

Is it possible to autowire `MyDecorator` in different places with different cache?
I can configure XML like this:

```xml
<bean id="id1" class="MyDecorator ">
    <property name="cache" value="Cache1" />
</bean>
<bean id="id2" class="MyDecorator ">
    <property name="cache" value="Cache2" />
</bean>
```

But is there more elegance way without addition of xml configs, only with annotation?

Correct code should be

```
    @Configuration
    public class AppConfig { 
@Bean
    public MyAdapter adaptedCache2() {
        return new MyAdapter (cache1);
    }

    @Bean
    public MyAdapter adaptedCache2() {
        return new MyAdapter (cache2);
    }}
```

according to [specs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch02s02.html) will be generated two beans adaptedCache1 and adaptedCache2 
and now i can 
autowire those beans with qualifiers adaptedCache1 and adaptedCache2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Java configuration (Spring 3.1) you can write:

```
@Bean
public MyDecorator decoratedCache1() {
    return new MyDecorator(cache1);
}

@Bean
public MyDecorator decoratedCache2() {
    return new MyDecorator(cache2);
}
```

Of course in this case `MyDecorator` does not need `@Component`:

```
@Component
class MyDecorator{
    private final Cache cache;

    public MyDecorator(Cache cache) {
        this.cache = cache;
    }

}
```

Comment: as understand in case above i have MyDecorator has to extend Cache I'm not sure if it is good idea

Comment: @Diyko: isn't this how *Decorator* pattern works? It extends/implements the same interface as wrapped object? Otherwise it is an *Adapter*...

Comment: seems i've got what you meant